# PHP [ERR_NO_SESSION] during dochecknewauctionext command on allegro Webapi

Tags: php, allegro-pl

While trying to execute command dochecknewauctionext I'm getting "[ERR_NO_SESSION]" error. I'm pretty new to this and I simply can't see what's wrong with the session id. Is the code incorrect? Or maybe the id changes - it connects for the second time during the command? How to fix/execute this commmand properly?
Here's the code. (All the 'xxx' were proper numbers while connecting to WebApi)

```
    <?php

class AllegroSOAP extends SoapClient 
{       
 const COUNTRY_TESTWEBAPI = 1;

 const QUERY_ALLEGROWEBAPI = 1;

 public function __construct() 
 {
  parent::__construct('https://webapi.allegro.pl.webapisandbox.pl/uploader.php?wsdl');
 }  
}

Class TestAllegro
{
 const WEBAPIKEY = 'xxx';

 const PASSWORD = 'xxx'; 
 // to samo, które używamy do zalogowania się w swoim Allegro
 const LOGIN = 'xxx'; 
 // ten sam, który używamy do zalogowania się w swoim Allegro

 private $wynik ='';  // wynik działania klasy
 private function conectAllegro ()
 {
  $r = new AllegroSOAP;

  //-pobieramy wersję WebAPI
 $version = $r->doQuerySysStatus(
        AllegroSOAP::QUERY_ALLEGROWEBAPI,
        AllegroSOAP::COUNTRY_TESTWEBAPI,
        TestAllegro::WEBAPIKEY); 

  //-logujemy się aby otrzymać numer sesji
 $session = $r->doLoginEnc(
        TestAllegro::LOGIN, 
        base64_encode( hash('sha256', TestAllegro::PASSWORD, true)), 
        AllegroSOAP::COUNTRY_TESTWEBAPI, 
        TestAllegro::WEBAPIKEY,
        $version['ver-key']); 
// sprawdzamy aukcje
  $this->wynik = $r->dochecknewauctionext(array($session['session-handle-part'],'fields' => array(
            array(
         'fid' => 1,   // Tytuł [Aukcja testowa]
         'fvalue-string' => 'Aukcja testowa',
         'fvalue-int' => 0,
         'fvalue-float' => 0,
         'fvalue-image' => 0,
         'fvalue-datetime' => 0,
         'fvalue-date' => '',
         'fvalue-range-int' => array(
                'fvalue-range-int-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-int-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-float' => array(
                'fvalue-range-float-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-float-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-date' => array(
                'fvalue-range-date-min' => '',
                'fvalue-range-date-max' => '')),
            array(
         'fid' => 2,   // Kategoria [Pozostałe > Pozostałe > Pozostałe]
         'fvalue-string' => '',
         'fvalue-int' => 1885,
         'fvalue-float' => 0,
         'fvalue-image' => 0,
         'fvalue-datetime' => 0,
         'fvalue-date' => '',
         'fvalue-range-int' => array(
                'fvalue-range-int-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-int-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-float' => array(
                'fvalue-range-float-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-float-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-date' => array(
                'fvalue-range-date-min' => '',
                'fvalue-range-date-max' => '')),
            array(
         'fid' => 4,   // Czas trwania [7]
         'fvalue-string' => '',
         'fvalue-int' => 2,
         'fvalue-float' => 0,
         'fvalue-image' => 0,
         'fvalue-datetime' => 0,
         'fvalue-date' => '',
         'fvalue-range-int' => array(
                'fvalue-range-int-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-int-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-float' => array(
                'fvalue-range-float-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-float-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-date' => array(
                'fvalue-range-date-min' => '',
                'fvalue-range-date-max' => '')),
            array(
         'fid' => 5,   // Liczba sztuk [100]
         'fvalue-string' => '',
         'fvalue-int' => 100,
         'fvalue-float' => 0,
         'fvalue-image' => 0,
         'fvalue-datetime' => 0,
         'fvalue-date' => '',
         'fvalue-range-int' => array(
                'fvalue-range-int-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-int-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-float' => array(
                'fvalue-range-float-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-float-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-date' => array(
                'fvalue-range-date-min' => '',
                'fvalue-range-date-max' => '')),
            array(
         'fid' => 8,   // Cena Kup Teraz! [100.00]
         'fvalue-string' => '',
         'fvalue-int' => 0,
         'fvalue-float' => 10000.00,
         'fvalue-image' => 0,
         'fvalue-datetime' => 0,
         'fvalue-date' => '',
         'fvalue-range-int' => array(
                'fvalue-range-int-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-int-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-float' => array(
                'fvalue-range-float-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-float-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-date' => array(
                'fvalue-range-date-min' => '',
                'fvalue-range-date-max' => '')),
            array(
         'fid' => 9,   // Kraj [Polska]
         'fvalue-string' => '',
         'fvalue-int' => 228,
         'fvalue-float' => 0,
         'fvalue-image' => 0,
         'fvalue-datetime' => 0,
         'fvalue-date' => '',
         'fvalue-range-int' => array(
                'fvalue-range-int-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-int-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-float' => array(
                'fvalue-range-float-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-float-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-date' => array(
                'fvalue-range-date-min' => '',
                'fvalue-range-date-max' => '')),
            array(
         'fid' => 10,  // Województwo [lewopolskie]
         'fvalue-string' => '',
         'fvalue-int' => 215,
         'fvalue-float' => 0,
         'fvalue-image' => 0,
         'fvalue-datetime' => 0,
         'fvalue-date' => '',
         'fvalue-range-int' => array(
                'fvalue-range-int-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-int-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-float' => array(
                'fvalue-range-float-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-float-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-date' => array(
                'fvalue-range-date-min' => '',
                'fvalue-range-date-max' => '')),
            array(
         'fid' => 11,  // Miejscowość [Poznań]
         'fvalue-string' => 'Poznań',
         'fvalue-int' => 0,
         'fvalue-float' => 0,
         'fvalue-image' => 0,
         'fvalue-datetime' => 0,
         'fvalue-date' => '',
         'fvalue-range-int' => array(
                'fvalue-range-int-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-int-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-float' => array(
                'fvalue-range-float-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-float-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-date' => array(
                'fvalue-range-date-min' => '',
                'fvalue-range-date-max' => '')),
            array(
         'fid' => 12,  // Transport [Kupujący pokrywa koszty transportu]
         'fvalue-string' => '',
         'fvalue-int' => 1,
         'fvalue-float' => 0,
         'fvalue-image' => 0,
         'fvalue-datetime' => 0,
         'fvalue-date' => '',
         'fvalue-range-int' => array(
                'fvalue-range-int-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-int-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-float' => array(
                'fvalue-range-float-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-float-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-date' => array(
                'fvalue-range-date-min' => '',
                'fvalue-range-date-max' => '')),
            array(
         'fid' => 14,  // Formy płatności [Platne z gory (przelew)]
         'fvalue-string' => '',
         'fvalue-int' => 1,
         'fvalue-float' => 0,
         'fvalue-image' => 0,
         'fvalue-datetime' => 0,
         'fvalue-date' => '',
         'fvalue-range-int' => array(
                'fvalue-range-int-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-int-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-float' => array(
                'fvalue-range-float-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-float-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-date' => array(
                'fvalue-range-date-min' => '',
                'fvalue-range-date-max' => '')),
            array(
         'fid' => 15,  // Opcje dodatkowe [Wyróżnienie]
         'fvalue-string' => '',
         'fvalue-int' => 8,
         'fvalue-float' => 0,
         'fvalue-image' => 0,
         'fvalue-datetime' => 0,
         'fvalue-date' => '',
         'fvalue-range-int' => array(
                'fvalue-range-int-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-int-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-float' => array(
                'fvalue-range-float-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-float-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-date' => array(
                'fvalue-range-date-min' => '',
                'fvalue-range-date-max' => '')),
            array(
         'fid' => 24,  // Opis [Opis testowej aukcji.]
         'fvalue-string' => 'Opis testowej aukcji.',
         'fvalue-int' => 0,
         'fvalue-float' => 0,
         'fvalue-image' => 0,
         'fvalue-datetime' => 0,
         'fvalue-date' => '',
         'fvalue-range-int' => array(
                'fvalue-range-int-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-int-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-float' => array(
                'fvalue-range-float-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-float-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-date' => array(
                'fvalue-range-date-min' => '',
                'fvalue-range-date-max' => '')),
            array(
         'fid' => 29,  // Format sprzedaży [Aukcja (z licytacją) lub Kup Teraz!]
         'fvalue-string' => '',
         'fvalue-int' => 0,
         'fvalue-float' => 0,
         'fvalue-image' => 0,
         'fvalue-datetime' => 0,
         'fvalue-date' => '',
         'fvalue-range-int' => array(
                'fvalue-range-int-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-int-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-float' => array(
                'fvalue-range-float-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-float-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-date' => array(
                'fvalue-range-date-min' => '',
                'fvalue-range-date-max' => '')),
            array(
         'fid' => 32,  // Kod pocztowy [60-687]
         'fvalue-string' => '60-687',
         'fvalue-int' => 0,
         'fvalue-float' => 0,
         'fvalue-image' => 0,
         'fvalue-datetime' => 0,
         'fvalue-date' => '',
         'fvalue-range-int' => array(
                'fvalue-range-int-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-int-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-float' => array(
                'fvalue-range-float-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-float-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-date' => array(
                'fvalue-range-date-min' => '',
                'fvalue-range-date-max' => '')),
            array(
         'fid' => 35,  // Darmowe opcje przesyłki [Odbiór osobisty]
         'fvalue-string' => '',
         'fvalue-int' => 1,
         'fvalue-float' => 0,
         'fvalue-image' => 0,
         'fvalue-datetime' => 0,
         'fvalue-date' => '',
         'fvalue-range-int' => array(
                'fvalue-range-int-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-int-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-float' => array(
                'fvalue-range-float-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-float-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-date' => array(
                'fvalue-range-date-min' => '',
                'fvalue-range-date-max' => '')),
            array(
         'fid' => 36,  // Paczka pocztowa ekonomiczna (pierwsza sztuka) [9.50]
         'fvalue-string' => '',
         'fvalue-int' => 0,
         'fvalue-float' => 9.50,
         'fvalue-image' => 0,
         'fvalue-datetime' => 0,
         'fvalue-date' => '',
         'fvalue-range-int' => array(
                'fvalue-range-int-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-int-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-float' => array(
                'fvalue-range-float-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-float-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-date' => array(
                'fvalue-range-date-min' => '',
                'fvalue-range-date-max' => '')),
            array(
         'fid' => 38,  // Paczka pocztowa priorytetowa (pierwsza sztuka) [11.00]
         'fvalue-string' => '',
         'fvalue-int' => 0,
         'fvalue-float' => 11.00,
         'fvalue-image' => 0,
         'fvalue-datetime' => 0,
         'fvalue-date' => '',
         'fvalue-range-int' => array(
                'fvalue-range-int-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-int-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-float' => array(
                'fvalue-range-float-min' => 0,
                'fvalue-range-float-max' => 0),
         'fvalue-range-date' => array(
                'fvalue-range-date-min' => '',
                'fvalue-range-date-max' => ''))),
    'private' => 0,
    'local-id' => 123123123
      ));
  unset($version, $session, $r);
 }
 public function wynik()
 {
  $this->conectAllegro();

  return $this->wynik;
 }

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pl" xml:lang="pl">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Allegro-testy</title>
</head>
<?php

$test = new TestAllegro;

echo '<pre><p>test</p>';
print_r($test->wynik());
echo '</pre>';

unset($test);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed. It was allegro's fault